# Find values of a, b and c for which $f(x)$ if continuous at $x=0$.

Tags: limits, continuity

> If given function $f(x)$ :
>   $$f(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
> (1+ax)^{1/x} \ \quad ;& x <0 \\ 
> b \ \ \qquad \qquad  \quad; & x = 0 \\ 
> \cfrac{(x+c)^{1/3} - 1}{x} ; &  x >0 
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>   Then find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ for which $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

This is what I've tried yet.

Since the given function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, therefore:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$

Hence, it comes out to be:

$$\begin{align} 
&\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} (1+ax)^{1/x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \cfrac{(x+c)^{1/3} - 1}{x} = b \\
\implies & e^a = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \cfrac{(x+c)^{1/3} - 1}{x} = b\end{align} $$

I got $e^a$ there by using the identity: $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+ax)^{1/x} = e^a$.

**Although, I want to make sure here, does this identity hold true for x tending to zero from right and left side, both...? Or is there any difference? (if the function is continuous)**

From this, I've got one thing at least:  $\color{blue}{e^a = b}$

Now, first thing that comes into my mind is L'H rule, although, I don't see any future set in it for this question (as it became nasty later on). Next thing which comes into my mind is taking *log* both sides.

But, am not sure how log will help us proceed here. On one side, it will be just $a$, not sure about the second side whose limit is yet to be calculated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It holds true that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{t}\right)^t=e^a$, hence the answer is yes by substitution $t:=\frac{1}{x}$.
2. Observe first that, if $c\neq 1$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)$ *doesn't exist* in $\mathbb{R}$, because the numerator tends to $c^\frac{1}{3}-1\neq 0$ and the denominator tends to $0$. Therefore, for $f$ to be continuous in $0$, $c=1$ is necessary.

   **Now** you can apply l'Hopital's theorem on the right side to obtain $b=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{3(x+1)^{2/3}}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: We can apply LH rule at numerators and denominators separately, right?

Comment: Aw.. I forgot this ^ actually! Sorry, LH rule surely seems to be handy here. Got it! Thanks a lot for your help, Mr. G.Sassatelli.

Comment: No, wait a second: I am terribly wrong! I'm editing right now!

Comment: Oh, okay! Take your time, Sir!

Comment: Done @KushashwaRaviShrimali

Comment: Thanks again Sir! But, am a bit confused, why is it so that c should necessarily be 1?

Comment: The fact is that [l'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) needs that numerator and denominator either both converge to $0$ or both diverge to $\infty$.

$c=1$, as I said, is necessary because if, say, $c>1$, then $$\lim{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+c}-1}{x}=\left[\frac{\sqrt[3]{c}-1}{0^+}\right]=+\infty$$
No continuous function can have an asymptote in a point of its domain.

Comment: Great, thanks again Sir!